# Flatten the tree path in SQL server Hierarchy ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, hierarchyid

I am using SQL Hierarchy data type to model a taxonomy structure in my application.
The taxonomy can have the same name in different levels

[image]

During the setup this data needs to be uploaded via an excel sheet.

Before inserting any node I would like to check if the node at a particular path already exists so that I don't duplicate the entries.
What is the easiest way to check if the node @ particular absolute path already exists or not?

for e.g Before inserting say "Retail" under "Bank 2" I should be able to check "/Bank 2/Retail" is not existing

Is there any way to provide a flattened representation of the entire tree structure so that I can check for the absolute path and then proceed?

[image]

Comment: It seems from your example and tag that you already know the answer - store this in a `hierarchyid` and use `ToString` to convert each node to a string path then compare. You might need to insert into a staging table first

Comment: The Path column I have is the ToString() representation. I need to be able to build the Flattened tree path. I currently don't know the way to get the Falttened Tree Path

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can do it [using a recursive CTE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx).

In each iteration of the query you can append a new level of the hierarchy name.

There are lots of examples of this technique on the internet.

For example, with this sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE Test
(id INT,
parent_id INT null,
NAME VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO Test VALUES(1, NULL, 'L1')
INSERT INTO Test VALUES(2, 1, 'L1-A')
INSERT INTO Test VALUES(3, 2, 'L1-A-1')
INSERT INTO Test VALUES(4, 2, 'L1-A-2')
INSERT INTO Test VALUES(5, 1, 'L1-B')
INSERT INTO Test VALUES(6, 5, 'L1-B-1')
INSERT INTO Test VALUES(7, 5, 'L1-B-2')
```

you can write a recursive CTE like this:

```
WITH H AS
(
    -- Anchor: the first level of the hierarchy
    SELECT id, parent_id, name, CAST(name AS NVARCHAR(300)) AS path 
    FROM Test 
    WHERE parent_id IS NULL      
UNION ALL
    -- Recursive: join the original table to the anchor, and combine data from both  
    SELECT T.id, T.parent_id, T.name, CAST(H.path + '\' + T.name AS NVARCHAR(300)) 
    FROM Test T INNER JOIN H ON T.parent_id = H.id
)
-- You can query H as if it was a normal table or View
SELECT * FROM H
   WHERE PATH = 'L1\L1-A' -- for example to see if this exists
```

The result of the query (without the where filter) looks like this:

```
1  NULL  L1      L1
2  1     L1-A    L1\L1-A
5  1     L1-B    L1\L1-B
6  5     L1-B-1  L1\L1-B\L1-B-1
7  5     L1-B-2  L1\L1-B\L1-B-2
3  2     L1-A-1  L1\L1-A\L1-A-1
4  2     L1-A-2  L1\L1-A\L1-A-2
```

Answer (score 0):

Google brought me here for flattening hierarchyid. Modified JotaBe answer to use hierarchyid.

Sample Data

```
CREATE TABLE #BankDemo  
(
    Node hierarchyid NOT NULL,  
    Name nvarchar(30) NOT NULL   
);

   INSERT #BankDemo  
    VALUES   
('/1/', 'Bank1'),  
('/2/', 'Bank2'),  
('/1/1/', 'Retail'),  
('/1/1/1/', 'Loans'),  
('/1/1/2/', 'Advances'),  
('/2/1/', 'Retail'),  
('/2/1/1/', 'Agriculture Loans'),  
('/2/1/2/', 'Advances');
```

Recursive Query

```
WITH H AS
(
    -- Anchor: the first level of the hierarchy
    SELECT Node, Node.ToString() as Path, Name, CAST(Name AS NVARCHAR(300)) AS FlattenedTreePath 
    FROM #BankDemo 
    WHERE Node.GetAncestor(1) = hierarchyid::GetRoot()      
UNION ALL
    -- Recursive: join the original table to the anchor, and combine data from both  
    SELECT T.Node, T.Node.ToString(), T.Name, CAST(H.FlattenedTreePath + '\' + T.Name AS NVARCHAR(300)) 
    FROM #BankDemo T INNER JOIN H ON  T.Node.GetAncestor(1) = H.Node
)
-- You can query H as if it was a normal table or View
SELECT * FROM H
```

Results of query

| Node | Path | Name | FlattenedTreePath |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0x58 | /1/ | Bank1 | Bank1 |
| 0x68 | /2/ | Bank2 | Bank2 |
| 0x6AC0 | /2/1/ | Retail | Bank2\Retail |
| 0x6AD6 | /2/1/1/ | Agriculture Loans | Bank2\Retail\Agriculture Loans |
| 0x6ADA | /2/1/2/ | Advances | Bank2\Retail\Advances |
| 0x5AC0 | /1/1/ | Retail | Bank1\Retail |
| 0x5AD6 | /1/1/1/ | Loans | Bank1\Retail\Loans |
| 0x5ADA | /1/1/2/ | Advances | Bank1\Retail\Advances |